How can I 'go to definition' programmatically using Lua?
Using an LSP in Neovim, you can go to an object's definition by placing the cursor over the symbol in question and hitting <C-]> or <gc>. I'd like to be able to use this behaviour in Lua, i.e. to be able to run something like :lua 'jump_to_definition("foobar")' and have the definition for foobar open as if I had entered <C-]> with my cursor over the foobar symbol.
Browsing the Neovim documentation, I see that <C-]> is powered by vim.lsp.buf.definition(options). The documentation about what exactly options should be is pretty cryptic, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to manually set the symbol to be looked up.
vim.lsp.tagfunc(pattern, flags) is a related function which seems a bit more programmable, but doesn't seem to do exactly what I want. Using the R language server, I can use this function to get a tag for a particular symbol, but only if I've previously looked up the definition using <C-]>. You can test this using, e.g. :lua print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.tagfunc("foobar", "cir", 0))).
For context, I'm trying to create a user command to conveniently go to an object's definition even if it doesn't appear in the file I'm currently looking at.

I'm guessing this feature doesn't exist because 'jump to definition' will necessarily require more context to be provided by the LSP than just the symbol itself. For example foobar + 1 is very different to "foobar is a variable". That said, my intuition is that it should be able to manually supply some fake additional context that will be correct about 95% of the time, at least for R.

If you're using COC as completion and LSP, then there is option of jumping on definition :call CocActionAsync('jumpDefinition') it supports in most LSP servers of COC
